# Derivative of a Function of the Diag function

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

Suppose there is a vector $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$. How would you find the derivative of:

$$ 
F(U)=trace\left(diag(U) A\ diag(U) \right)
$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \succ 0 $ and where $diag(\cdot)$ creates a diagonal matrix with $(\cdot)$ on the leading diagonal. Where the derivative is taken with respect to the vector $U$, i.e.

$$
{\partial F(U) \over \partial U } \\
$$

I am more interested in the method used. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the solution I identified.

Due to the trace operator evaluating the above is equivalent to evaluating:

$$
{\partial \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} u_i \ A_{(i,i)}u_i\right)\over \partial U }= 
\left( \begin{align}
\begin{array}
{\partial \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} u_iA_{(i,i)}u_i\right)\over \partial u_1}\\
{\partial \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} u_iA_{(i,i)}u_i\right)\over \partial u_1}&\\ 
\vdots \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ &\\
{\partial \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} u_iA_{(i,i)}u_i\right)\over \partial u_n}&\\
\end{array}\end{align}\right) \\ 
$$

which becomes:

$$
{\partial \left( trace(diag(U)\ A\  diag(U)) \right)\over \partial U} = 2\ diag( A) U
$$

Comment: You can also derive this using two identities involving the Hadamard product 
$${\rm Diag}(x)\,A\,{\rm Diag}(y)=A\odot xy^T$$
$${\rm Tr}(A\odot xy^T)=x^T(I\odot A)y=\phi$$
So that
$$d\phi=y^T(I\odot A)dx+x^T(I\odot A)dy$$
Setting $y=x=u$ this becomes
$$d\phi=2u^T(I\odot A)du$$
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial u}=2(I\odot A)u$$

Comment: That is a nice alternative thanks @greg

Comment: @greg, Could you add this as an answer? If not, would you mind I'd do it and mark it as Community?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two useful identities involving the Hadamard $(\odot)$ product of a matrix and two vectors.
$$\eqalign{
A\odot xy^T &= {\rm Diag}(x)\cdot A\cdot{\rm Diag}(y) \\
{\rm Tr}\Big(A\odot xy^T\Big) &= x^T\left(I\odot A\right)y \\
}$$
Note that $(I\odot A)$ preserves of the main diagonal of $A$ but sets all off-diagonal terms to zero.

It is a diagonal matrix and therefore $\;(I\odot A)^T=(I\odot A)$

These identities can be used to re-write the function
$$\eqalign{
F &= {\rm Tr}\Big({\rm Diag}(u)\cdot A\cdot{\rm Diag}(u)\Big) \\
  &= u^T\left(I\odot A\right)u \\
}$$
and then calculate its differential and gradient 
$$\eqalign{
dF &= du^T\left(I\odot A\right)u \;+\; u^T\left(I\odot A\right)du \\
   &= 2u^T\left(I\odot A\right)du \\
   &= g^Tdu \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}
   &= g \;=\; 2\left(I\odot A\right)u \\
}$$